# How to Assign Private Static Ip to GCE instance using terraform in separate terraform deployments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created private static IP using terraform and now want to assign it to GCE instance by directly given the name of static Ip but getting the error that its not able to allocate.
if I do it in same dployment i.e create and static ip and then create VM and assign it to VM it works

but not separately , how to fix this?
The reason I am doing it separately because I want static IP still to be there when I recycle my VM  using terraform destroy and create again I should be able to assign same IP to it.

Comment: Can you provide TF code that produces the error and exact error message.'

Comment: Do a `data` lookup on the resource instead? or just destroy using the `-target` flag?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data from the previous deployment like that

```
data "google_compute_address" "my_address" {
  name = "foobar"
}
```

Documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/compute_address)